# Get nearby points with RoR and postGIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis

i'm trying to get, given a longitude and latitude, return all the records from a table (which has lon and lat attributes) which are in a 1 mile radius.
I was thinking i should do something with ST_Dwithin and ST_MakePoint but not sure how to use it.

this is what i have until now:

```
def get_nearby(longitude, latitude)
  Device.where(ST_DWithin(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude, 1.60934)))
end
```

[UPDATE]
So, my final function was:

```
  scope :nearby_devices, ->(lon,lan) { where(
    <<-SQL,
      ST_DWithin(
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude), 4326),
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326),
        1.60934
      )
    SQL
  lon,lan)}
```

My model has two float attributes: `longitude` and `latitude`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)'s parameters are `geometry, geometry, distance`, so you're on the right track. Assuming `Device` has a lat/lon column named `coordinates`, you need to [make a point](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) of the correct type (probably WGS 84) and compare that to `coordinates`.

```
Device.where(
  <<-SQL,
    ST_DWithin(
      coordinates,
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326),
      1.60934
    )
  SQL
  longitude, latitude
)
```

Comment: would this be ok? Device.where(
    <<-SQL, ST_DWithin(
              ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude),
              ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lan), 4326),
              1.60934
            ) SQL. longitude and latitude are the column name from devices and lon, lan are the params from the specific point i want to get the devices nearby from.

Comment: You'll need to call `ST_SetSRID` on both points to make them the same type, then that should work fine

Comment: hey, how should i replace the ? with the lon and lan parameters?

Comment: `ActiveRecord#where` replaces question marks in the SQL string with the rest of the parameters you provide, like I've done in my example. Check out [the Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions).

Comment: this is actually giving me back all of my devices. Not caring about the 1.60934 distance i specified. clues?

Answer (score 0):

Here i post the final version: this solution let me measure the distance in meters:

```
scope :nearby_devices, ->(lon, lat) {
    Device.where( "ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude), 4326),
      ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326)) <= 1609 ", lon, lat)}
```

Hope it can help somebody